# Looking for a Kitchen Sink Hole Cover with a opening

Tags: kitchen-counters, kitchen-sink, countertops

I installed a DrinkPod that connects to my cold water link under the sink.

I routed the hose through an unused hole in our kitchen counter top. Is there a Sink Hole Cover, but maybe with a smaller opening in the middle to make this look cleaner? Or what would you suggest? The sink hole opening is about 2" in diameter.

[image]

Comment: If this were mine, I’d route the hose thru a new hole behind the machine so the hose is hidden.  Then in this hole I’d put a “sink soap dispenser” (google that, my link won’t paste for some reason).  Of course I also would have hooked it up just like you did to start, once I knew I was going to keep the machine tho....

Comment: If you want to leave it as-is, there are plastic hole covers used to neaten up holes in desks for passing cables through.  They have a small hole or slot intended for the cable.  Check the big hardware chains or office supply stores.

Comment: @Tyson should submit this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @Tyson Yeah, that's probably the best, but I didn't want to drill another hole in the countertop. So I removed the soap dispenser to route through there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy [a 1-3/4-Inch Sink Hole Cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FFHBJ58) and drill a hole in the middle. voila problem solved.

You may want to get a [grommet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BO4WSG) to protect the hose from the edge of the hole you are drilling. You would need a grommet with a hole sized right for your pipe and then drill the appropriate size hole for the grommet to fit in.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I bought both. Thanks!

Comment: I also ordered this:
https://www.amazon.com/Metal-Grommet-Office-CyanCloud-Sliver/dp/B073X5TMJB

Its actually what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you or a friend had a work shop with a wood turning lathe you could easily make a plug of hardwood such as maple that would fit into the hole and have a smaller hole in through the center. You could finish the wood with a durable oil or poly and then set in to place with some silicon sealing compound. The plug could also be painted with a durable epoxy paint to do more of a color match.

The plug could look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thats a cool project, but I don't have a lathe handy. Thanks though!